# problem with the vector algebra

Tags: vectors

I have the vector $\vec c$ that is:

$\vec c= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\vec r_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i}$

where $\vec r_i$ is a vector and $m_i$ is a scalar

I need to proof the folowwing equality for any vector $\vec r $

$ \sum_{i=1}^n m_i |\vec r-\vec r_i|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n m_1|\vec r_i-\vec c|^2+m|\vec r-\vec c|^2$

and i known that $m= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i$

I try to replace the vector $\vec c$ in the equality but but i get confused with the vector algebra.

Comment: Hint: convert the norms to dot products and expand

Comment: $\vec{c}$ is the center of mass of your system, and your relation is the very well known parallel axis theorem, which you can find all over the web.

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the property $$|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|^2 = (\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}).(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}) = |\textbf{x}|^2 - 2\textbf{x}.\textbf{y} + |\textbf{y}|^2$$

LHS reduces to the following

$$= m|\textbf{r}|^2 - 2\textbf{r}.\left(\sum_1^n m_i\textbf{r}_i\right) + \sum_1^n m_i \textbf{r}_i.\textbf{r}_i$$

$$= m\left(|\textbf{r}|^2 - 2\textbf{r}.\textbf{c} + |\textbf{c}|^2\right) + \sum_1^nm_i(|\textbf{r}_i|^2 - |\textbf{c}|^2)$$

Can you proceed further?